# Rattle, R, Error en botón ejecutar

Tags: r, rstudio, macos, ejecutar

Tengo el siguiente error al intentar cargar cualquier tipo de dato en rattle[image: example input data]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto y como lo puedo solucionar?

Esto usando lo siguiente :
-Versión de R : "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
-macOS High Sierra versión 10.13.6

Comment: Me huele a una mala instalación. ¿Podrías reinstalarlo?. Hay quien encuentra la solución descargandose e instalando esta versión: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pmml/pmml_1.3.tar.gz

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español!, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. En cuanto a tu pregunta, te sugiero que pruebes establecer el lenguaje al inglés antes de ejecutar rattle, así: `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")` pruebalo y cualquier cosa nos cuentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio Moracho, cambiar el lenguaje resolvió el problema. ¿Porqué con solo cambiar el idioma se pudo resolver el problema?

Comment: Ahí escribí una respuesta, aparentemente un issue del sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación de los problemas de instalación](https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-troubleshooting.html) de `rattle` hay un "issue" en Mac/OSX con respecto a la internacionalización en la que están trabajando, mientras tanto sugieren configurar el idioma a inglés:

```
> Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
> library(rattle)
> rattle()
```